# Should service layer classes be singletons?

Tags: spring, n-tier-architecture

I am using Spring framework.  Should my service classes be created as singletons?  Can someone please explain why or why not?  Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes, they should be of scope `singleton`.
Services should be stateless, and hence they don't need more than one instance.

Thus defining them in scope `singleton` would save the time to instantiate and wire them.

`singleton` is the default scope in spring, so just leave your bean definitions as they are, without explicitly specifying the `scope` attribute.

You can read more about scopes [in the spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes).

Comment: Thanks.  I am new to Spring, I know how to write a singleton class, but how do I set a "scope of singleton" using Spring?

Comment: Oh I didnt see your comment about it being the default scope.  Could you please explain to me where this scope is set and configured just so I can have an idea of how everything is wired? Thanks again.

Comment: I added the link to my answer.

Comment: Thanks!  Good to know that I don't have to make any changes!

Comment: @Bozho if you need to use state/insatnce variables within a singleton spring service, are there any drawbacks or better ways :  http://stackoverflow.com/q/11126684/106261

Answer (score 2):

Spring is easier to use if you stick with singleton-scoped beans. Singletons are its "default position", if you like. Yes, it supports other scopes (using `scope="xyz"` in the XML file), but it makes things harder to use and hurts performance.

Essentially, unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, stick with singletons.

Answer (score 1):

You need mostly singletons. (Spring default.) Singletons must be thread-safe, because parallel requests will use the same single instance. In fact, they must be completely stateless, because it can be destroyed and recreated at any time.

If you need to keep track of state inside of your bean (you should not, this should be in the database or stored in the request), you will get many instances of the same type of bean, memory usage goes up with the number of requests, whereby with singletons you will still have just one instance.

Even if you scope you beans to a request, they must still need be at least thread-safe (requests coming from the same browser at the same time).

Comment: Spring singleton beans can *not* be created and destroyed at any time, I don't know where you got that from (maybe you're confusing them with EJB session beans).  Also, mutable state within a Spring singleton is absolutely fine, you just need to be aware of what operations can be done on that shared state.

Comment: `Thready safety` is about the implementation, not the bean scope. A singleton class could be not-thread-safe and a prototype class could be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Service layer should be Singleton, otherwise for every incoming request a new object will be created and these objects are heavy contains business logic and lots of line of code. They must be Singleton.