# Does @Service guarantee uniqueness in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, service, annotations, scope

Assuming a class is annotated with `@Service`, does Spring guarantee a unique instance of the class for injection? Or should I put `@Scope("singleton")` on every service?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html)

> The singleton scope is the default scope in Spring

So there is no need to set this explicitly.

Comment: +1 for a quick and concise answer a few seconds before I could finish my thoughts. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a discussion I found on CodeRanch:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/586038/Spring/Spring-treat-Service-Singleton

And an answer from a different Stackoverflow post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2173019